# How to read text from a certain layer of a pdf using adobe acrobat javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I'm trying to read text from a layer of adobe. The problem is that even if I turn off the other layers, my script still reads the text from all layers.

```
var layers = this.getOCGs(); 
var myLayer;
for(var i=0;i<layers.length;i++){
    if(layers[i].name!="TheLayerIWant")
        layers[i].state=false;
    else{
        layers[i].state=true;
        myLayer=layers[i];
    }    
}
var word="";
for(var i=0;i<this.getPageNumWords(0);i++)
{
    word=this.getPageNthWord(0,i,false);
    console.println(word);
}
```

This script turns off all the layers except the one I need to read.
Then I try to read from "TheLayerIWant", but it reads the text of all layers on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible using Acrobat JavaScript. All text will be read regardless of its visibility.